# Why firebase_core package is not working and causing problem while launching a Windows app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart-pub

When I add the [firebase_core package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) in pubspec.yaml and try to build the app for Windows, I got this error:

```
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:71 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    C:/Users/soft/Desktop/flutter_application/build/windows/extracted/firebase_cpp_sdk

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)
```

When I delete the package from pubspec.yaml the app launchs without any error. I tried to create a new app and linked with Firebase, then adding the same package, and  got the same error .

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting the build directory: or try deleting the build directory in your Flutter project and then rebuilding the app. You can delete the build directory by running rm -rf build on macOS/Linux or rmdir /s /q build on Windows.

Comment: i did and i tried `flutter clean` too but i still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was get this error, and i fixed it.
This error came when the debbuging of your main.dart file's was interrupted.
So, for fixing it do these commandes:
**1- Flutter clean
2- Flutter pub get**
And wait the entire debugging of your main.dart file, even if it's taking many times.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it becase i change the git branch and package name. And when flutter try to download file for build folder, I may interupt the process so the download process is not fully complete.

Try `Flutter clean` then `Flutter pub get`. After success, run code use `flutter run -d windows -v` command, it will run and show the progress(percentage) of downloading file. If u use run use play button or just `flutter run` you will not view the progress and feel this program is not responding because it takes to long to run.

Hope it helps you.